# How to convert list of strings date into another format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

I tried this code to convert string of dates into  another format but i have number of strings which is not taken by this code.

```
import dateparser
dateparser.parse(str1[0], date_formats=['%d %B %Y'] )
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: So what format are the dates that you're having trouble with in?

Comment: Im having dates in for example 30 Jan 2010 , I want it in 2010-01-30

Comment: If you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Post the problematic part of your data-samples. Edit your question to add the needed information so we can easily help you.

Comment: I tried import datefinder
string_with_dates = """
                    entries are due by January 4th, 2017 at 8:00pm
                    created 01/15/2005 by ACME Inc. and associates.
                    """
matches = datefinder.find_dates(string_with_dates)
for match in matches:
    print match it prints everything well but how I stored this output into list

Comment: I used s=[] , s.append(match) but I don't want date time text to be added in it.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your date format using `datetime`, which is available in the standard library:

```
from datetime import datetime

x = '30 Jan 2010'
res_single = datetime.strptime(x, '%d %b %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# '2010-01-30'

lst = ['30 Jan 2015', '10 Dec 2010', '20 Apr 2020', '15 Feb 2005']
res_lst = [datetime.strptime(x, '%d %b %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in lst]
# ['2015-01-30', '2010-12-10', '2020-04-20', '2005-02-15']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime` and a straightforward `for` loop.
Preparations:

```
from datetime import datetime #import
dates = ['20 Feb 2010', '21 Mar 2012', '22 Apr 2014', '24 May 2016'] #sample dates
parsed_dates = [] #initialise empty list to store the parsed dates in
```

Actual loop:

```
for date in dates:
    d_parsed = datetime.strptime(date, '%d %b %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') #transform date
    parsed_dates.append(d_parsed) #add transformed date to new list
```

This results in

```
print(parsed_dates)
#>>> ['2010-02-20', '2012-03-21', '2014-04-22', '2016-05-24']
```

---

If your dates are hidden but always in the same way - e.g. always preceded by a string of different lengths but situated in the end, as your example in the comments - use this code:

```
from datetime import datetime #import
hidden_dates = ['For example16 Apr 2018','another example04 Apr 2018', '20 Feb 2010', 'testdtas_21 Mar 2012', 'some characters24 22 Apr 2014', 'words 24 May 2016'] #sample dates
parsed_dates = [] #initialise empty list to store the parsed dates in

for hidden_d in hidden_dates:
    date = hidden_d[-11:]
    d_parsed = datetime.strptime(date, '%d %b %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') #transform date
    parsed_dates.append(d_parsed) #add transformed date to new list

print(parsed_dates)
#>>> ['2010-02-20', '2012-03-21', '2014-04-22', '2016-05-24']
```

Comment: What how will I separate  dates from multiple strings in list without  using datefinder and then stored the data into list to format the date?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain what you mean, and post the code in the question? :)

Comment: I have a string like ['For exampleApr 16, 2018','another exampleApr04, 2018'.........] I am able to get dates with date finder but these method dates are not in same order as in sentence, my question is is there any other method from which I can separate the dates from sentence like [Apr16, 2018, 'Apr 04, 2018'....]as in question I have asked for single string I can extract it but for num.ber of strings loop was not able to work, I hope its clear.